# WebpackOptionsValidationError: configuration plugins[12] misses the property apply

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I recently upgraded my project from vuetify 1.5 to 2.1.. I also updated the required dependencies and installed fibers, deepmerge, sass, sass-loader in devdependencies. 
     Now when I run "yarn serve" it throws following error.

```
    WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
     - configuration.plugins[12] misses the property 'apply'.
           function
       -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
    WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
     - configuration.plugins[12] misses the property 'apply'.
       function
       -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
        at webpack (/home/usman/projects/project-crm/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:31:9)
        at serve (/home/usman/projects/project-crm/frontend/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:137:22)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I don't have a clue where is this error occuring. I searched on internet but didn't found solution on 
this error...

```
configuration.plugins[12] misses the property 'apply'.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK people!!!
I've found a solution(trick). Off course it is a trick the way I see it but it is working absolutely fine to me. Remember this error happened to me due to upgrade from vuetify 1.5 to 2.1....
Steps I took were,

- Created a new project(name = candy) with latest Vue and Vuetify.
- Installed all dependencies and devDependencies in this new project(candy in my case) which I had in my original projects `package.json` file.
- You can open `package.json` file of your original project and terminal in new project(candy) and run commands `yarn add "package name in original project` or `npm install "package name`.
- Then copied this(candy) `package.json` file and pasted it in my original project folder and renamed these files and folder to old.
- File & folder == `node_modules` to `node_modules_old`, `package.json` to `package_old.json`, `vue.config.js` to `vue.config_old.js`, `yarn.lock` to `yarn_old.lock`.
- Copy only package.json of candy project to the original project's folder.
- Run command `yarn install` or `npm install`.
- And the server runs now.

Further, you will have to set your code according to the project. It can be in vue.config.js mostly or in babel config file or webpack.config.js.